# Xcode: How to change icon in xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, ios7, xcode5

I'm trying to change the icon in my old app project. I've updated to xcode 5 and want to get a "ios 7 design". However, you don't change the icon the way you did before. I've seen that you are supposed to have e file called Images.xcassets with should include your icons, but I don't have that one because you only seem get it if you are making a new project.

This should be very easy, what should I do??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the project icon in the file list, choose the General tab, and scroll down to the App Icons section. From there you can either:

- use the Source popup to choose "Don't use asset catalogs"
- create a new asset catalog and drag your icons into it; clicking the little grey arrow icon next to the popup will take you to the icons in your assets catalog

Comment: Oh I opened another of my apps in xcode, and there I have all the places where you can drag you icons, but I don't have it on this one.. WTF?

Comment: If you don't have an asset catalog, you should see a list of icon kind/dimensions/resource.

Comment: I couldn't find the General tab in the project, but I did find it in the Targets.

Comment: @JohnK With the project selected in the file navigator, "General" is the first (leftmost) panel listed in the editor (along with "Capabilities", "Info", "Build Settings", etc. The bar at the top doesn't look like a tab bar so much in Xcode 5 (the tabs themselves aren't drawn, only the titles), but it still works that way.

Comment: For whatever reason I'm not seeing it in Xcode 5. But it hardly matters since I got it to work through the Target settings. The reason I posted was in case others had the same difficulty. Thanks for your answer, Caleb!

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Project Navigator
2. Click on root (project properties)
3. Click on tab General
4. Sections App Icons
5. Click on gray arrow

(BTW This is the same as find Images.xcassets in project navigator)

Now you can drag and drop icons to proper placeholders.

Comment: Gray arrow didn't work for me. But adding xcassets in project helps! Thank you, Rio

Answer (score 0):

Porting an App from xcode 4.6 to xcode 5 I didn't use The Images.xcassets file. Where in xcode 4.6 was the place to put icons and launch screens, in xcode 5 there is a large list of icon sizes to put the icon app for iOS 7, iOS 6.1 and prior versions, spotlight...